# C# Synchronisation with screen updates

Tags: c#, winforms, view, synchronization

I have the following Problem:
My application does a screen-update and should make a screenshot of the new view after that.
The code is as follows:

```
    public ViewModelBase Screen {
        get {
            if (_screen == null) {
                Screen = new DataSourceChooserScreenViewModel(this);
                History.ChangeHistory(ADD_ITEM);
            }
            return _screen;
        }
        set {
            _screen = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Screen");

            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

The screen update is done in "OnPropertyChanged("Screen")" and the screenshot is taken in "History.ChangeHistory(ADD_ITEM)".
The methods calling the setter for "Screen" follow all the same scheme:

```
//Do something
Screen = otherScreen;
History.ChangeHistory(ADD_ITEM);
//Do something else
```

And here's the problem:
The screenshot is made before the screen has been updated although the execution order says something else.

To solve the problem by myself I tried several things:
Busy waiting in ADD_ITEM
Waiting by timer in ADD_ITEM
Usage of asynchronous threading with waiting on PropertyChangedEvent via BeginInvoke() and EndInvoke()
Usage of System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

All tries had the same result: The screenshots was done before the screen became updated. In the attempt with the usage of timers I figured out, the screen becomes updated **after** ADD_ITEM was performed. So I suggest the compiler makes some implicit threading and I don't know how to fix/prevent it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry for stupid assumption... Did you try using System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents() a few times before screenshot?

Comment: And also, try making a screenshot in another thread. Call DoEvents first and then start new thread via ThreadPool.QueUserWorkItem

Answer (score 1):

When I have to do something like that, I always use timer event that will fire AFTER everything is processed.  It would be one-shot timer event and usage will be something like this:

To fire it:

```
Timer t=new Timer();
t.Tick+=DoAfter;
t.Interval=100;
t.Start();
```

What needs to be done is here:

```
void DoAfter(object Sender, SomeArgs a)
{
    Timer t=(Timer)Sender;
    t.Stop();
    t.Dispose();
    //  perform your stuff here
    DoStuff();
}
```

That way you have a good chance that message loop will do everything and the screen updates will finish BEFORE timer fires.

Comment: If you're using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, you're guaranteed that it's finished painting. It resolves to `WM_TIMER` under the hood, which is the lowest "priority" message in Windows. It's synthesised by `GetMessage` if there is a timer that's elapsed and if there's nothing else to do.